# How to read an Environment variable from Java code

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have a properties file that needs to be loaded into a java program. Part of the path is defined by the system environment variable `JAVA_TOP`. When i give the full path it recognizes the file. Otherwise it won't. I tried giving file path as:

```
<JAVA_TOP>/abc.... 
$JAVA_TOP/abc...
JAVA_TOP/abc
```

None of them seem to work. Please let me know how to read the environment variable `JAVA_TOP` from the java application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am assuming, you are looking at reading the environment variable `JAVA_TOP` in your Java code. `System.getenv("JAVA_TOP")` should return the value of `JAVA_TOP`

Comment: indeed this is what i want. Thank you