# How am I able to access environment variables in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables

Based on Tomcat official documentation and from what I've seen elsewhere online, the Java servlet code deployed to Tomcat, cannot access Environment variables. Only the values explicitly setup in setenv.sh or catalina.sh can be accessed from the Java code.

But, when I'm testing out my Tomcat setup, I can clearly access environment variables from the Java code. These variables have not been setup in setenv.sh or catalina.sh

I'm using tomcat version 8.5.35 and in their own RUNNING.txt, it states that environment variables cannot be accessed from the Java code.

Is the fact that I'm able to access them a bug? Has anyone else encountered this before?

Some more points that might be relevant:

- I have a local setup of tomcat. The tomcat installation resides in a local folder in my home directory
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Start tomcat with bin/startup.sh

Comment: If you pass them using "-D", the VM should have them. Tomcat cannot access any other env variables due to sandbox. No bug, just normal.

Comment: @atmin My question is that I'm able to access environment variables. 

The question is how am I able to access them when tomcat docs state that env variables cannot be accessed.

Comment: That's completely impossible. Tomcat is started in the Java VM. The Java VM does not know anything about e.g. $PATH unless You pass it explicitly when booting the tomcat.

Comment: Hence my question :)

I tested multiple times and my tomcat installation is definitely able to access env variables. Just not able to figure how this is possible.

Comment: @atmin As any other process, a running Java VM will inherit the environment from its parent process. So it does know about $PATH. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685865 on how to access it.