# What is the best way to read environment variables from files in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm looking for best practice of reading values such as AWS access and secret keys. In python I use dotenv to load the values into variables. Is there a similar plugin for Scala ?

Comment: OK.  So this question is contradicting itself.  Environment variables come from the environment.  Not from files.  If you read them from a file they are not environment variables.  So ... are you actually asking how to read **configuration** parameters/properties/variables from files?

Comment: For what it is worth, in Scala `sys.env` is an **immutable** map.  New keys or values cannot be injected into it.  The equivalent of python's `dotenv` is not implementable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read an Environment variable from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685865/how-to-read-an-environment-variable-from-java-code)